# Getting principal from AD on a linux machine

Tags: linux, active-directory

When a Linux client has joined (free)Ipa, for example, the user can run an `ipa-getkeytab` command to get a keytab for a principal.

Is there something equivalent for a Linux client that is AD-joined?

Comment: Would `kinit` or `ktutil` not work? i.e. the default Kerberos tools provided by `krb5-workstation`?

Comment: @shearn89 I don't think so - I think kinit gets some tickets, and ktutil allow one to create a keytab, but none of those - to the best of my knowledge - has the functionality of fetching a principal from AD.

Comment: I've used `ktutil` to create kerberos keytabs for service accounts before in e.g. big data platforms. By then name, `ipa-getkeytab` sounds pretty similar o_O

Comment: Oh! I guess I don't know if ktutil can retrieve an already-created keytab... so potentially different